# "Rupees is/are interchangeable"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which of these sentences is correct?

> Rupees **are** interchangeable with dollars

or

> Rupees **is** interchangeable with dollars.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple...
Nouns have 2 groups for number: count and non-count. If you can count them individually, they are count. If you can only measure them, they are non-count (or uncountable). They are handled differently for S-V agreement. 
Rupees are countable, and take the form of the verb applying to plural. Money, on the other hand, is a concept, uncountable, but still measurable. It takes the singular form of the verb.
Thus we would have:

Money is...

but,

Rupees are.

Other example of uncountable nouns: sugar, trouble, gasoline

Examples of count: apple, problem, gas-tank

There some exceptions to be careful of such as school subjects, diseases, names of countries ending in s, etc. and a few others like "news" .

examples:
Mathematics, Physics, Statistics, Measles, Mumps,

all of these, including "news" is always singular because the words end in "s". They are not plural.

Answer (score 0):

**Rupees are interchangeable with dollars** is the correct usage

Comment: Why is that the correct one?

Comment: Because 'Rupees' is a  plural form of 'Rupee'.

Comment: @aish123 Please review the [help] guidance on crafting good answers.

Comment: One more thing you should know. If you leave such a short answer without research/reference to support your answer, (1) it will be more likely to get a downvote, (2) it will be flagged as low quality for its length and content, (3) it could be deleted by users. If you have such a short answer, please leave it as a comment. It is not an answer.

Comment: My work here is done.