# My bank account now has 500 dollars, 50% of which was (or were) earned from my office job. Should I "was" or "were" in the clause?

Tags: grammar

The word "dollar" is a countable noun, so I shall use the plural form of the linking verb in the clause?

Comment: The answers to these questions might help: [Are amounts of money singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/119536/)  [“Rupees is/are interchangeable”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82023/) [Why “was” not “were” in “Nearly £20 was taken from my bank account”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/34412/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While individual dollars are countable, you're describing a collective *amount* rather than a collection of individual bills.  Amounts are generally uncountable, but the convention seems to vary depending on how you phrase the sentence:

> A large amount of money **was** stolen from the bank.
>
> Several million dollars **was/were** stolen from the bank.

Which you use for percentages depends on the actual collective noun.  As with the above example, with money it seems like you can use either.

> 50% of the five million dollars in donations **has/have** been earmarked for disaster relief.

I'm personally inclined to use the singular, since that emphasizes the total *amount* rather than the *number* of bills, but that's just opinion.

See also:

- ["Rupees is/are interchangeable"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82023/)
- [Why "was" not "were" in "Nearly £20 was taken from my bank account"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/34412/)